# Converting WAV file audio input into plain ASCII characters

Tags: c++, c, ascii, wav

I am working on a project where we need to convert WAV file audio input into plain ASCII characters. The input WAV file will contain a single short alphanumeric code e.g. asdrty543 and each character will be pronounced one by one when you play the WAV file. Our requirement is that when a single character code is pronounced we need to convert it into it's equivalent ASCII code. The implementation will be done in C/C++ as un-managed Win32 DLL. We are open to use third party libraries. I am already googling for directions. However, I will really appreciate it if I can get directions/pointers from an experienced programmer who has already worked on similar requirement. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: sox -t auto -w -s -r 8000 -c 1 {input_file} {output_file

Comment: So, where is the problem?

Comment: Is your problem with the WAV format or with the speech recognition?

Answer (score 0):

ASCII characters like `Az09` are only a portion of the ASCII Table. WAV files like any other file is stored and accessed in bytes.

1 byte has 256 different values. Therefore `one can't simply convert bytes into Az09 since there are not enough Az09 characters.`

---

You'll have to find a library which opens WAV files and creates the `wave format` for you. In relation to the wave's *intensity* and *length*, a chain of Az or Az09 characters can be produced.

I believe you're trying to convert the wave to a series of notes. That's possible too, using the same approach.

Comment: This hint is in "pronounced". A wav file containing `asdrty543` will be several seconds long, i.e. many kilobytes.

Comment: @MSalters Either way, he still has to read WAV file's binary format!